# Simulator for BlackBerry 9300

Tags: blackberry, mobile

Which simulator should be used to test the application that support's BlackBerry 93* OS and 
Which simulator can I use for Iphone.

Comment: Hi!, Can you please give some detailes/lincs/reference for BlackBerry 93*? you can check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no BlackBerry 9300 model as far as I know, anyhow you can use 9350 that is 4.7.x series simulators

Answer (score 1):

If there was I would be very surprised. BlackBerry and Iphone are completely different OS's and such would need different emulators.

Btw even if there was some mixed hack of an emulator that claims to do both I wouldn't trust it.

For Blackberry you can download it on their website and the the same goes for Iphone.

Comment: @durbin thanks for your response I have edited my question since I want to test it for both different emulators will be also fine my problem is that I have to support BlackBerry 93* OS and I am not sure which version of emulator would suite the requirements currently I am using BlackBerry 9530 simulator.